# Erlang ftp:open with tls option timeouts

Tags: ssl, ftp, erlang

I was wondering if someone had used Erlang `ftp:open/2` with `tls` option? Everytime I put `tls` options in the function, I get a timeout. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: It will be helpful to add some more information. Maybe some part of the code, the log, your ftp server config, etc.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve